# React Js Call function from a function with same component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

how startserver function will call searchaws info function

```
startserver : function(){
var self =this;
   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                            url: "",enter code here
                            data: JSON.stringify(amazonEc2ManagerBean),
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function() {
```

// i want to call searchawsinfo function. 
                                                self.searchawsinfo; // i want to call searchawsinfo function.

```
                                    }


                    });
},

searchawsinfo : function(){
// it should be called from startserver function , i guess i am missing something
},
```

Comment: Format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.searchawsinfo(); will be used instead of self.searchawsinfo;

Answer (score -1):

```
function(){ 
          var self = this; 
          $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "",enter code here
          data: JSON.stringify(amazonEc2ManagerBean), 
          contentType: "application/json", 
          dataType: 'json', 
          success: function() { 
                               self.searchawsinfo(); // i want to call searchawsinfo function.
                               }
 });
},

searchawsinfo : function(){
 // it should be called from startserver function
},
```